# CasperJS PhantomJS SSL issues

Tags: javascript, ssl, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

When I try run this official CasperJS example:

https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/master/samples/screenshot.js

with this code addition:

```
casper.on("resource.error", function(resourceError){
     console.log(JSON.stringify(resourceError));
     console.log('Unable to load resource (#' + resourceError.id + 'URL:' + resourceError.url + ')');
     console.log('Error code: ' + resourceError.errorCode + '. Description: ' + resourceError.errorString);
});
```

I have following error:

```
Error code: 6. Description: SSL handshake failed
```

and script stop executing.

I use CasperJS 1.1.0 beta3, and PhantomJS 1.9.7

Flags like --ignore-ssl-errors=true and --ssl-protocol=any don't help at all.

Sites without ssl certificate work properly...

Any workaround for this issue?

Please help

Comment: you can always try opening an issue for that repo in github

Comment: Have you tried to pass both commandline options at the same time? Have you tried to update PhantomJS to version 1.9.8 (note CasperJS may have its own version, so you might need to delete that)?

Answer (score 2):

@Vlatko , it seems to me, your problem is related to security / SSL rule. I have faced sometimes this kind of problem and could solve using the CasperJS configuration parameters in the code call (or if you prefer, the source file).

The following configuration commands can be used in the Calls of your test file:

```
casperjs --web-security = no --ssl-protocol = any --ignore-ssl-errors = yes test YOUR_FILE.js
```

In cases had some security problem, this code snippet solved my problems, because he will not let the security options http / https active, allows any type of protocols are used and ignore SSL errors.

Comment: thank you @DiegoB the `--ignore-ssl-errors=yes` helped me to understand and resolve an issue I was having with a casperjs/phantomjs script that had been working on older Debian releases. Since Debian buster upgrade I was having issues. FYI I didn't need the other arguments in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but now I can run the .js file by adding few ignore commands:

my_ubunto:~$ phantomjs --web-security = no --ssl-protocol = any --ignore-ssl-errors = yes test_my_error.js

I hope it will be helpful.